# Nuxtjs 'npm generate ' not working give 401 error for some pages

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I'm using nuxtjs for my project fronted.. after I completed some of my development and I,m try to host that with shared hosting so I run the `'npm run generate` command. But some pages it get this error.

[image: Image of error]

*This is my Bank page Code*

```js
<template>
  <v-layout style="display:block">
    <h2>Banks Details</h2>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="9">
        <v-data-table
          :headers="tableHedaer"
          :items="list.data"
          @update:page="nxtPage"
          :loading="loading"
          dense
          height="calc(100vh - 285px)"
          disable-items-per-page
        >
          <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
            <v-btn icon color="error">
              <v-icon @click=";(selectID = item.id), (dialogSureR = true)"
                >mdi-delete</v-icon
              >
            </v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="3">
        <v-card
          style="border-radius: 0px; border:1px solid black;"
          height="calc(100vh - 180px)"
          flat
        >
          <v-card-text>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
              Add new Bank
            </v-col>
            <v-divider />
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.bankCode"
                outlined
                label="Bank Code"
                hide-details
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
              <v-select
                v-model="form.accountType"
                :items="types"
                outlined
                label="Account Type"
                height="30"
                hide-details
              ></v-select>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.bankName"
                outlined
                label="Bank Name"
                hide-details
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.branch"
                outlined
                label="Branch"
                hide-details
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.accountNo"
                outlined
                label="Account Number"
                hide-details
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12" class="text-right">
              <v-btn @click="addBank()" color="indigo" small dark depressed
                >save</v-btn
              >
            </v-col>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <!-- remove dialog -->
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogSureR" max-width="290">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline">Are You Sure?</v-card-title>

        <v-card-text> </v-card-text>

        <v-card-actions>
          <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>

          <v-btn @click="dialogSureR = false" color="red" text>
            No
          </v-btn>

          <v-btn @click="removeBank(selectID)" color="green darken-1" text>
            Yes
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <snack :s-text="sText" :s-color="sColor" :snackbar="snackbarv"></snack>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import snack from '~/components/Loaders/snackBar'
export default {
  components: {
    snack
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tableHedaer: [
        {
          text: 'ID',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'id'
        },
        {
          text: 'Bank Code',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'bankCode'
        },
        {
          text: 'Account Type',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'accountType'
        },
        {
          text: 'Bank Name',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'bankName'
        },
        {
          text: 'Branch',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'branch'
        },
        {
          text: 'Account Number',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'accountNo'
        },
        {
          text: 'Remove',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'action'
        }
      ],
      types: ['saving', 'current'],
      list: [],
      loading: false,
      sText: '',
      sColor: '',
      snackbarv: false,
      dialogSureR: false,
      selectID: '',
      form: {
        bankCode: '',
        accountType: '',
        bankName: '',
        branch: '',
        accountNo: ''
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // snackbar modal value false time
    snackbarv() {
      if (this.snackbarv === true) {
        if (this.sColor === 'success') {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.snackbarv = false
          }, 2000)
        } else if (this.sColor === 'warning') {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.snackbarv = false
          }, 5000)
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.snackbarv = false
          }, 3000)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const empcget = await $axios.$get('/admin/allBanks')

    return {
      list: empcget
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // get all banks data
    getAllE() {
      this.loading = true
      this.$axios.$get(`/admin/allBanks`).then((data) => {
        this.loading = false
        this.list = data
      })
    },
    // data table next and prev click load paginate data
    nxtPage(no) {
      this.loading = true
      this.$axios
        .$get(`${this.list.path}?page=${no}`)
        .then((data) => {
          this.list = data
          this.loading = false
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.loading = false
          console.log(error)
          alert('error')
        })
    },
    // add new bank
    addBank() {
      if (
        this.form.bankCode !== '' &&
        this.form.accountType !== '' &&
        this.form.bankName !== '' &&
        this.form.branch !== '' &&
        this.form.accountNo !== ''
      ) {
        this.$axios
          .$post(`/admin/saveNewBank`, this.form)
          .then((data) => {
            this.snackbarv = true
            this.sText = 'Done'
            this.sColor = 'success'
            this.list.data.push(data.data)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.loading = false
            console.log(error)
            alert('error')
          })
      } else {
        this.snackbarv = true
        this.sText = 'Please fill all fields'
        this.sColor = 'warning'
      }
    },
    removeBank(id) {
      this.$axios
        .$delete(`/admin/removeBank/${id}`)
        .then((data) => {
          this.snackbarv = true
          this.sText = 'Done'
          this.sColor = 'success'
          this.nxtPage(this.list.current_page)
          this.dialogSureR = false
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.loading = false
          console.log(error)
          alert('error')
          this.dialogSureR = false
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
::v-deep .v-data-footer__select {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
</style>
```

And if I remove below part and run the `npm run generate` command it  works with no error

```
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const empcget = await $axios.$get('/admin/allBanks')

    return {
      list: empcget
    }
  },
```

*laravel controller function*

```php
    /**
     * return all bank details
     * 
     * @return array all bank details
     */
    public function getAll(){
        $data = tblBank::paginate(50);
        return new BankDetailsResource($data);
    }
```

whats the wrong with this?

Thank You..

Comment: and how does your server side looks like?

Comment: I,m using laravel API for the backed. I'm update the question and and the laravel controller function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm forget to add nuxtjs auth module middleware to some pages this error given by that pages after adding the middleware error is gone

Answer (score 1):

You are calling asyncData twice which is probably causing your error. If you want to make multiple axios requests in your asyncData you can use promise chaining like so:

```
async asyncData ({ $axios }) {
  const [empcget, customerget] = await Promise.all([ 
    $axios.get('/admin/allBanks'),
    $axios.get('/admin/allCustomers'),
  ])

  return {
    list: empcget.data,
    customers: customerget.data
  }
},
```

Comment: really sorry for that that is my mistake there only have  one async method. second one is another page async method. That's page is working with no error  run the 'generate' command that why I add it to this page and test it I'm forget to remove it in this question sorry for that I'm update the question and remove it.. That is not the cause for this error.